# is their any way to use Angular 8 Library in Angular 4 application

Tags: angular

I have project developed in Angular 4 application - it has multiple component and project is too big to be converted into Angular 8 in one go therefore it needs to be converted in phases. That is why looking for solution if some component can be changed to Angular 8 library (which is client requirement as well) which can be consumed in Angular 4 application.

since routing of some core functionality has been changed so when i import Angular 8 library in angular 4 application it may look for @angular/common/http which does not exist in Angular 4. If i add node_modules folder inside library then typescript conversion issues occurs as both Angular version is using different Angular cli and typescript version - please correct if i am wrong ...

Able to successfully use Angular 8 library in Angular 4 application

Comment: Unlikely, I upgraded my library to Angular 8 and it stopped working in Angular 6 and 7 projects so I downgraded to 7 as it still worked in 6 and 8. I doubt that you will get an Angular 8 library to work in 4. Just run Angular upgrade and see what happens. Hardest part of an upgrade is the RxJs 5 to 6 upgrade as all the fluent methods became pipeable functions. But the effort is well worth it.

Comment: I wouldn't let my project get too many versions out of date. I would do an upgrade at least once every major update.

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite the project. As I'm sure you have, take a look at [this tool](https://update.angular.io/#4.0:8.0) and see what the steps are for your specific case. While there are various conversion automation tools out there, none of them (in my experience) seem to do the job well.

For your "phases," I would go through component by component and upgrade them using Angular's update guide checklist. With that said, if you have to update every component significantly, it may be easier to rewrite the code.

4 to 8 is a big jump so whether you want to painstakingly go through the checklist or do a rewrite, it won't be a walk in the park.

As for http, you should be able to do this conversion before running the update commands. For node_modules, you shouldn't have to touch this - npm will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the metadata version from 4 to 3 in library's metadata.json file, then able to fixed this error. But don't know that am in correct way or not.